# Can I directly query a join table to get the "created_at" date of an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, many-to-many

I have a `Member` model and a `Tag` model. They have a many-to-many relationship established using activerecord associations. As a result, there is a `members_tags` simple join table reflected in my schema. This table by default has a `created_at` column. I wish to access this information to see the datetime at which a tag was applied to a member. Is this possible?

Comment: You can if the assocations is `has_many through:` - please include the relevant model code in the question.

Comment: They're both `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't be that difficult to just create my own join table with its own model that I could query directly. Just wondering if I can do something similar with things as they are.

Comment: No, since  habtm is headless (no model) there is no way to fetch additional data from the join table. It is really straight formward if you use `has_many through:` though. https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

Comment: Thanks very much. I was tinkering with raw SQL querying but was having no luck.  I had something going on like this:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT member_id, tag_id FROM members_tags WHERE created_at BETWEEN '#{DateTime.now}' AND '#{DateTime.now - 3.months}'").rows`

This wasn't returning any results..

I have barely any SQL experience so it could be a problem with my query..

Comment: I would just rename the table `member_tags` and setup a model instead. The values in that query should not be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `many to many` relationship between **Member** and **Tag**, you will have a connected model **ModelTag** or **TagModel** depends on how you named it). When you created the joined table `model_tags` (or `tag_models`) you will have access to the `created_at` column as well.

Let's say you have a ModelTag model. You can access any of its instance `created_at` column with, for example:

```
ModelTag.first.created_at
```

if you want to access the column created_at of all instances:

```
ModelTag.all.map {|mt| mt.created_at}
```

Dunno if it's what you want?

Comment: As the commenter above (max) posted, activerecord `has_and_belongs_to_many` doesn't allow for a model. This article that max shared explains it well: https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

The solution was to generate a model and establish my own `has_many, through:` relationships, which is actually what you stated above, but you didn't consider that rails allows for multiple types of many-to-many relationships. My question was pretty vague though.. 

Either way, thanks for offering some support.